# Would linux poll return -1 and set the errno 115?

Tags: c, linux

the code is:

```
struct pollfd _conncet_client[1];
int _nfd = 1;
memset(&_conncet_client[0],0,sizeof(pollfd));
_conncet_client[0].fd = fd;
_conncet_client[0].events = POLLIN ;

int _ret;
int _loop_max = 5;
for( int i=0;i<_loop_max;i++)
{
    _ret = ::poll(_conncet_client, _nfd, (int)(timeout_sec*1000));
    if ( _ret < 0 && errno == EINTR )
        continue;
    else
        break;  
}
return _ret;
```

I just want to know would poll return -1 and set errno 115(EINPROGRESS)

Comment: According to [the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) the `poll` functions doesn't return with an `EINPROGRESS` error. Perhaps you can elaborate on the *actual* problem you are having? And please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Get rid of the bogus underscores. They're reserved in many contexts, not free for you to use. (Cargo culted from Python?)

Comment: Also you tagged this c but it looks like c++...

Comment: From the manual page cited by @Someprogrammerdude: "A value of 0 indicates that the call timed out and no file descriptors were ready." May I assume this is what you were after?